# Using Regex on a list of strings with question marks

Tags: python, regex

first, I know there are similar questions but I could not find anything that really matched my case.

I have a large string from which I want to cut out some texts.

```
import re
largeString = 'abcdefgTHIS NEEDS TO GO?abdehdfenTHIS NEEDS TO GO TOO?asjdhnasjdf'
itemList =['THIS NEEDS TO GO?','THIS NEEDS TO GO TOO?']
<<<some code>>>
Out: 'abcdefgabdehdfenasjdhnasjdf
```

I tried this:

```
for i in itemList:
  largeString = re.sub(str(i), '', largeString.rstrip())
```

The Problem is the question mark in the search strings- I know that usually I would do 'THIS NEEDS TO GO\?'. Unfortunately, the list is very large and I cannot change it manually.

Is there a way to make regex ignore the question mark feature?

Any help or idea is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Your example is really simple and is something a simple `replace()` would also achieve and doesn't have the problem with the question mark `?`.
You are also applying the regex inefficiently if you are storing a bunch of patterns that is then turned into nothing. And by "disallowing" the question mark it is not a valid regex pattern. You should implement regex properly or look for something like `replace` if your use case is really that simple.

Comment: No, in reality the use case is not as simple of course.. I already got the help I needed in one of the answers. Thanks for your suggestion, will have a look into the replace function as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings inside of `itemList` only contain strings, (don't contain any regex) then you can use `re.escape` on it before giving it to any search-parameter. As the name suggests, it will then go over the string, and escape all of the characters that have special meaning in `regex`.

```
import re
largeString = 'abcdefgTHIS NEEDS TO GO?abdehdfenTHIS NEEDS TO GO TOO?asjdhnasjdf'
itemList =['THIS NEEDS TO GO?','THIS NEEDS TO GO TOO?']
for item in itemList:
  largeString = re.sub(re.escape(item), '', largeString)
```

Output:

```
>>> largeString
'abcdefgabdehdfenasjdhnasjdf'
```

Comment: Yes that works! Great, I didn't know the escape expression. Thanks a lot!

Comment: As your edit says this would no longer be regex. The question mark meaning in regex would no longer work but so would many other things. A proper approach to this would to use `str.replace()`.

Comment: @TinNguyen absolutely, that would be a better solution for this specific problem. However, if they ever need to use this in conjunction with a regular-expression, they could just concatenate the regex to the `re.escape` sequence.